# Error Gradle sync failed: Failed to find CMake

Tags: gradle, cmake, synchronization

I try to run an empty project in android studio by using C++.

Error:

Gradle sync failed: Failed to find CMake.
            Install from Android Studio under File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools/CMake.
            Expected CMake executable at C:\Development\android-sdk\cmake\bin\cmake.exe.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

I saw android studio sit for help
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#download-ndk

...there was an image:

https://developer.android.com/studio/images/projects/ndk-install_2-2_2x.png

i saw "File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools/CMake." and there was no Cmake option to enable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:
there was a problem with connection... i used a good VPN and it solved!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips may be helpful

Go to the "Tools" menu

Then select "Android"

Then click "**SDK Manager**"

[Open SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VIuv.png)

you will find **CMake**

select and install CMake

[install CMak Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otcOp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3 in OS X

Go to top menu:
`Android Studio > Preferences... > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`

Choose the tab named `SDK Tools`. If there is nothing to show, see status bar, it could be loading... Wait awhile and you will see CMake option

Just check and apply. Wait for installation to finish. Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **SDK Manager** ( Double Shift -> Search SDK Manager )
2. Click on **SDK Tools **
3. Find **CMake**
4. Click Apply

Comment: `Android Studio > Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (tab)`
Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/rCzO8tc.png